# How to execute dotnet application with cron?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core

I developed an application using the `NetCore` technology which allow to executea application on `Linux` environment.

I actually not able to find any tutorial that could help me to run the application with a cron job.

The goal is to have my application always run online because it need to store data inside database.

Comment: Yes it’s possible, just like any other application. What is the problem in doing so?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen do you know some tutorial that I can follow to achieve that?

Comment: The cron manual?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen no my question is based on how to have the application always online on linux

Comment: Please note the title asks a yes/no question, the question asks how to run it in cron and now you have a third question. Please edit the question to have the exact question, and only one. If it’s “how to keep an application running” and you’re just guessing it can be done with cron, don’t ask how to run it with cron. It gets confusing.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the second example on https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/07/writing-a-linux-daemon-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

I sense this question is more about Cron than about .net core.

If you have an application and you have installed the runtime so you know how to run it.

Then in Cron you just set it to run every 10 minutes, and check: "Don't run if already running".

Then if your code is set up never to terminate, but terminates anyway then Cron will start it up again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the cron idea sounds good but how can I setup this? I a newbie on ubuntu